# Calculate number of grouped rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count, group-by

I have 2 tables, Requests and Responses

Requests:

```
RequestId  UserId  InsertDate
1           1       5/4/2013
2           2       6/4/2012
.           .          .
.           .          .
```

Responses:

```
Responseid  Requestid(FK)  ResponseCode  
    1           1              A   
    2           1              V
    3           1              M   
    4           2              A
    5           2              S   
    6           2              D
    .           .              .
    .           .              .
```

Request is considered as "Passed" if response codes A and D are received (like request with id 2 in my example). I want to write a sql queries that will return 3 things:

- number of "Passed" requests
- RequestIDs of those requests that pass
- RequestIDs of those requests that didn't pass

I wrote something but I don't like it and I suppose there is better way. My query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
(
  SELECT count(*) as c, req.RequestID
  FROM Responses res inner join Requests req 
  on req.RequestID = res.RequestID
  where 
      res.ResponseCode = 'A' or
      res.ResponseCode = 'D' 

  group by req.RequestID
)cc

where c = 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass

```
SELECT r1.RequestID
FROM Responses R1
JOIN Responses R2
  on R2.RequestID = R1.RequestID
 and R1.ResponseCode = 'A' 
 and R2.ResponseCode = 'D'
compute count(r1.RequestID)
```

(not positive on the compute syntax)

not pass

```
SELECT distinct (r1.RequestID)
FROM Responses R1
FULL OUTTER JOIN Responses R2
  on R2.RequestID = R1.RequestID
 and R1.ResponseCode = 'A' 
 and R2.ResponseCode = 'D'
WHERE R2.RequestID is null 
   OR R1.RequestID is null
```

pass

```
SELECT r1.RequestID
FROM  Responses R1
WHERE R1.ResponseCode = 'A' 
INTERSECT 
SELECT r1.RequestID
FROM  Responses R1
WHERE R1.ResponseCode = 'D'
```

not pass

```
SELECT r1.RequestID
FROM  Responses R1
EXCEPT
SELECT r1.RequestID
FROM  Responses R1
WHERE R1.ResponseCode = 'D'
   OR R1.ResponseCode = 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

To return the request ids that have both response codes A and D, one way is to use `HAVING` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT res.requestId
FROM Responses res inner join Requests req 
  on req.RequestID = res.requestid
WHERE res.ResponseCode IN ('A','D')
GROUP BY res.requestId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT res.ResponseCode) = 2
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3a3a/4)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of another fundamentally different way of doing this (i.e. without the subquery or CTE which would be equivalent).  However, I would test explicitly for the "A" and "D" values separately:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c, req.RequestID
FROM Responses res inner join
     Requests req 
     on req.RequestID = res.EquifaxIDCompareRequestID
where res.ResponseCode in ('A', 'D')
group by EquifaxIDCompareRequestID
having SUM(case when res.ResponseCode = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       SUM(case when res.ResponseCode = 'A' then 1 else 0 end)
```

The `having` clause is similar to your outer `where` clause, except it is check that both "A" and "D" are in the result set.

There is another approach using a join or subquery.  Something like this:

```
select EquifaxIDCompareRequestID
from Requests req
where EquifaxIDCompareRequestID in (select RequestID from responses where ResponseCode = 'A') and
      EquifaxIDCompareRequestID in (select RequestID from responses where ResponseCode = 'D')
```

Answer (score 1):

The below gives, for each requestId, whether it passed or not and the total number (passes or fails) in the group that it is in (i.e. if it passed, the total number of requests that passed; if it failed, the total number of requests that failed).

```
with myCTE as
(
    select rq.requestId, case when rA.responseCode='A' and rD.responseCode='D' then 1 else 0 end as passed
    from dbo.Requests as rq
    outer apply
    (
        select top (1) re.responseCode
        from dbo.Responses as re
        where re.requestId=rq.requestId
            and re.responseCode='A'
    ) as rA
    outer apply
    (
        select top (1) re.responseCode
        from dbo.Responses as re
        where re.requestId=rq.requestId
            and re.responseCode='D'
    ) as rD
)
select *, count(*) over (partition by m.passed) as totalNumInGroup
from myCTE as m
```